# Sonarqube Time machine api: Reading past measures on a class-specific level

Tags: asp.net-web-api, sonarqube, metrics, timemachine

I need to read the metrics (violations, nloc) of specific classes using the time machine web api in order to calculate the most important violations. I already read that it is not possible to retrieve this information, because Sonar does not want the database growing rapidely.

Anyway, this post was from 2011. Is it now possible to retriev this information somehow? What would be the alternative.

Thank you very much for your response,
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is still not possible.